How to model time series with Fourier series?
I want to apply Fourier series to a time series and then compare its estimates to the actual values. The data is related to the monthly rainfall of a city from 2000 to 2023. I used the following commands, but this command is not executed for large data. Can anyone help me?
data={1.56, 1.06, 2.62, 2.45, 0.33, 2.22, 0.21, 0.05, 0.6, 3.23, 0.77, \
2.36, 1.16, 1.91, 2.23, 3.06, 1.65, 0.09, 0.42, 0.07, 0.14, 0.34, \
4.22, 2.15, 2.83, 0.68, 2.8, 10.39, 4.17, 5.1, 0.78, 0., 0., 0.75, \
2.89, 4.79, 1.08, 2.51, 2.67, 5.74, 1.36, 1.39, 0.32, 0.12, 0., 0., \
2.37, 1.55, 0.99, 1.29, 1.2, 7.35, 8.94, 0.2, 2.28, 0., 0., 0.33, 3., \
0.77, 2.89, 1.19, 1.03, 6.73, 5.11, 0.51, 0.02, 0.36, 0.39, 0.3, \
1.27, 0.63, 2.55, 1.43, 2.5, 4.58, 1.2, 0., 0.02, 0., 0.05, 6.9, \
2.44, 0.57, 1.17, 0.12, 2.56, 4.77, 2.78, 2.57, 0.15, 0.81, 0.15, \
0.3, 1.3, 0.71, 0.07, 3.18, 7.5, 0.97, 1.31, 0.02, 1.93, 0.02, 2.52, \
4.59, 0.83, 0.18, 0.73, 1.06, 4.7, 2.51, 0.18, 3.4, 0., 0., 2.16, \
0.98, 3.9, 0.99, 1.82, 5.33, 1.73, 4.8, 2.6, 17.16, 11.03, 0.97, 0.2, \
0.78, 0., 0., 0.61, 1.84, 4.14, 7.84, 4.17, 0.04, 1., 0.48, 0.95, \
1.38, 2.23, 0.65, 2.53, 0.6, 2.15, 3.41, 2.21, 1.6, 1.41, 0., 0.48, \
0.47, 1.74, 4.19, 3.45, 4.36, 0.93, 4.52, 3.73, 0.73, 0.46, 0., 0.05, \
0.22, 3.15, 1.5, 2.4, 0.42, 3.82, 0.49, 5.06, 0., 1.79, 0.12, 0.17, \
1.67, 3.01, 1.56, 1.18, 1.33, 1.98, 2.52, 3.55, 0.09, 0.02, 2.09, \
0.52, 2.06, 4.42, 1.04, 0.92, 0.28, 4.12, 6.55, 1.08, 3.61, 0.38, 0., \
0.45, 2.33, 1.43, 4.71, 0.14, 0.46, 1.2, 7.79, 1.46, 1.45, 0., 1.5, \
0.02, 0.74, 2.31, 2.8, 3.07, 8.25, 5.05, 4.18, 2.77, 1.2, 0., 0., \
0.98, 0.96, 0.72, 8.88, 4.12, 3.49, 5.18, 6.08, 2.54, 0.52, 0.05, 0., \
0.15, 2.23, 0.38, 1.33, 3.67, 2.36, 2.87, 6.61, 3.84, 0.15, 1.99, \
1.5, 0.02, 1.63, 6.21, 2.93, 1.96, 3.41, 3.41, 2.74, 3.75, 0., 1.4, \
2.18, 0., 0.76, 0.73, 3.85, 2.38, 1.16, 1.4, 2.68, 4.51, 0.36, 0., \
0., 0.43, 1.04, 1.45, 0.12, 2.14, 0.49, 5.6, 2.09, 2.51, 1.06, 0.2, \
0.02, 0.43, 2.96, 1.65, 1.89};

months = Range[1, 288];

rain = data;

T=288;

n = 5 
fourierSeries = 
 FourierTrigSeries[
  InterpolatingPolynomial[Transpose[{months, rain}], x], x, n]

originalDataPlot = 
  ListLinePlot[Transpose[{months, rain}], 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[Large], PlotMarkers -> Automatic}, 
   PlotLabel -> "Original Monthly rain", 
   AxesLabel -> {"Month", "Rain (mm)"}, PlotRange -> All];

fourierSeriesPlot = 
  Plot[fourierSeries, {x, 1, T}, PlotStyle -> Blue];

Show[originalDataPlot, fourierSeriesPlot, PlotRange -> All]


You mention comparing the Fourier results to the actual data.  Are you interested in predicting future rainfall or just closely recreating the raw data?

When you have a numerical time history then Fourier is the best approach.
First I plot your data to see if there are regularities.
  ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> All]


By eye your data does not have a periodic form but looks random.
Now we take the Fourier transform, I first remove the mean value which will otherwise dominate:
fd = Fourier[data - Mean[data]];
ListLinePlot[Abs[fd], PlotRange -> All]


This is the modulus spectrum. There are two main peaks at 24.8 and 49 which could be the first and second harmonic of the data.
If you want the amplitudes of the cosines then this will be the real values. The amplitude of the sins will be the imaginary values.
Some details of Fourier are given here.
When using Fourier it assumes your data is from equally spaced time steps. Is your data organised like that?
I hope that helps.

I have to disagree with the claim that a Fourier analysis is the "best approach" for time series.  And I am nitpicking a bit here.  Reasonable approaches are those that satisfy the objectives (for which the OP has not described very well).  If the objective was to examine the monthly variability in average monthly rainfall, then DateListPlot[Table[Mean[data[[Range[k, Length[data], 12]]]], {k, 1, 12}], {2000, 1}, Joined -> True] is very informative.

@JimB You make a good point. There are indeed many analyses you can do to time histories to see underlying statics. You may be correct that the OP wants monthly averages. I was just suggesting how he might proceed with Fourier analysis as this was his starting point.  I agree we need to know more about what the OP wishes to do. The title of his post also suggest Fourier analysis.

Sorry, my comment wasn't meant as a criticism (although I see it might have sounded that way).  I think that one of the advantages of these forums is that we can give the OP advice that they didn't know they needed.  I would hope that if I asked a question about physics (for which I know little), that someone responding would either correct me or point me to resources to better understand subtleties that I wasn't aware of.  So, yes, you addressed what the OP asked.

Thanks for your advice, how can to improve the command and reduce the error?

I used this command and the results were as follows (RMSE=2.44 and r=0.076). Is there a way to improve it?

I think we need more information from you. Can you edit your question so that it is clear what you want. What is your objective? When you say you used "this command" which command are you talking about? Is this anything to do with Fourier transforms which is the main heading for your question?

Modest thresholding might elicit an idea of when rain levels are low vs moderate vs high. For example newdata = Map[Piecewise[{{0, # <= 4}, {5.5, 4 <= # <= 7}}, 8] &, data]; ListLinePlot[newdata]

My goal is to use the Fourier series to estimate monthly rainfall. Then compare the estimated (Fourier series) and actual values with (RMSE, r). For this purpose, I used the "FourierTrigSeries" command to increase the accuracy by changing n.
